# Laravel 8 belongsTo relationship not returning data on User model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a Laravel 8 API and want to automatically join `user_settings` onto a `user` whenever the `User` model is queried.

My thinking is that I can achieve this with the [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) relationship since `user_settings` "belongs" to a user.

However, when I attach this to my `UserSetting` model and query a user I'm not seeing any user settings attached to my User despite having data in the `user_settings` table.

Where am I going wrong?

**Model: `User`**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class UserSetting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'user_settings';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'theme',
        'refreshButtonPlacement',
        'animationSpeed',
        'fetchTimeout'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the comment.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserSetting::class);
    }
}
```

**Model: `User`**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;


class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'last_login_at' => 'datetime'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I also tried using a [One To One](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relationship and defined a `settings` method on my `User` model but in Tinker when I ran `User::findOrFail(1)->settings;` I had nothing either.

Comment: Can you show the function you are using? Normally you would need to call the `->with(...)` function if I am not mistaken,

Comment: Yeah sure, I'm calling: `Auth::user()` and expect my user and user settings to be in there, I also tried: `User::where('id', Auth::id())->first();` and this didn't give me my user settings either

Comment: Yes because the settings are not automaticcaly retrieved... for that you will have to call the ->with() method: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: To answer your question from the deleted answer, you explain the problem as a https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one relationship, therefore you will never use hasMany().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationship setup:

```
class User extends Model
{
//some custom stuff
    /**
     * Get the phone associated with the user.
     */
    public function user_setting()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserSetting::class);
    }
}
```

```
class UserSetting extends Model
{
    //some custom things
    /**
     * Get the user that owns the comment.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Afterwards you can use [eager laoding by default](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default), in your case you will have to add `$with = ['user_setting']` to your `User` class.

You could also use the `->with()` method, for that you will have to use either:

```
 User::with('user_setting')->find(Auth::id());
//or
Auth::user()->with('organisation')->first()
```

Laravel doesn't load the relationship values in every call because of the obvious overhead. So you will either define the relationship to be loaded by default or you will have to work with the `->with()` method for eager loading the relationship.

Comment: That's excellent, got that in my model now with the `$with`

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your `User` model 
And you can access the user settings through a dynamic attribute `$user-> user_setting`
on each `User` model instance
For more informations
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

```
    public function user_setting(){
       return $this->hasOne(UserSetting::class);
}
```

Comment: This answer does not contain an explanation why you should do it like that neither is this the correct approach

Comment: Why isn't this the right approach @Aless55?

Comment: Can anybody confirm if this solution worked? This might be helpful for me too.

Comment: You just have to try to see @James

Comment: The right approach is to use a one-to-one relationship and then use eager loading with the `->with()` method

Comment: you could also define the static property `$with = ['user_setting'];` in your user model instead of using `->with()`

Comment: Ok I will try it

Comment: I have correct it, is  method  hasOne () you must call, not hasMany()